# IE not firing onchange event when clicking outside the window

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom-events, ecmascript-5

In IE if I change something in the textbox, the `onchange` event is not fired if I click onto another window. This seems to be a bug that Chrome does not have.  As I am relying on this event to fire predictably before an `onblur`, are there any suggested workarounds?

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function change1() {
    var div = document.getElementById("output");
    div.innerHTML = "onchange" + "<br />" + div.innerHTML;
}
function focus1() {
    var div = document.getElementById("output");
    div.innerHTML = "onfocus" + "<br />" + div.innerHTML;
}
function blur1() {
    var div = document.getElementById("output");
    div.innerHTML = "onblur" + "<br />" + div.innerHTML;
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<input id="dog" type="text" onchange="change1();" onfocus="focus1();" onblur="blur1();"></input>

<div id="output">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```